# Term for a set of vectors with equal magnitudes?

Tags: vectors, terminology

Is there a mathematical term for a set of vectors which all have the same magnitude?

For my motivation in asking this: I realize that "vectors of equal magnitude" isn't too hard to say. But ideally there would be some kind of adjective, as it seems very useful for expressing the concept of things being equally valuable but by different qualities. Flavors at an ice cream store for instance, maybe you like them all equally, but they each taste different. Maybe what one lacks in the "texture" dimension it makes up for in the "flavor" dimension. I would like to say "the flavors are _______"

Or, characters in a fighting video game. Each one is different, but ideally none of them will overall be stronger or weaker than the other. In game design terminology we could say "the characters are balanced".

Comment: In the real case, vectors of equal magnitude are a circle. (Draw it.)

Comment: Ah, I could have been more clear: I am asking about a set of any amount of equal-magnitude vectors, not a set of all possible equal-magnitude vectors. In other words, a term for any subset of a circle (or higher dimensional versions of one).

Comment: In two dimensions then, that's some n-gon. There may not be one nice word for what you're looking for.